# Duvida no plugin Jquery Filer

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, multiple-file-upload

Estou tentando usar este plugin de upload muito legal que achei, [Jquery Filer 1](https://github.com/CreativeDream/jquery.filer)

So que não estou conseguindo fazer 2 coisas nele. Veja se vocês conseguem me ajudar.

1- Quando clico no botão da lixeira nas miniaturas das fotos ele remove a foto não não consegui achar um jeito dele disparar um Ajax para eu também remover o arquivo físico.

2-Como eu faço para que depois do Upload da imagem eu consiga trocar o nome do arquivo que aparece quando se posiciona o mouse sobre a imagem?

Obrigado

Ps. Se alguém conhecer outro plugin que faça algo semelhando é só falar.

Comment: 1 - `onRemove: function(){}` 2 - `<div class="jFiler-item-info"><span class="jFiler-item-title"><b title="{{fi-name}}">{{fi-name | limitTo: 25}}</b></span></div>`. Observe o {{fi-name}}, ali você troca pelo nome do seu arquivo. Acredito que seja isso mesmo... ( https://github.com/CreativeDream/jquery.filer )

Comment: @Rafael Withoeft eu vi isto mas por exemplo o que eu devo fazer dentro do funcion do onRemove, ele não passa valores do que esta sendo excluído, pelo menos não vi na documentação. No item 2 eu vi isto mas não achei como subistituir a variavel fi-name após o upload com o nome do novo arquivo gereado. Se tiver como posta algum codigo simples para eu ver. Muito obrigado

Comment: do remove já consegui fazer um exemplo que depois você pode implementar. Estou vendo sobre o nome agora...

Comment: Legal. No aguardo. Muito obrigado

Comment: Joao, olha... para remover achei um meio... mas sobre o nome, acredito que não tem.. :/

Comment: Joao, posso te recomendar outro? Achei uma solução para você, ele gera um nome do lado do servidor retorna o novo nome, mas não exibe pro usuário (se quiser é possível sim), ele armazena para caso precise ser deletado... ele manda o nome que está do lado do servidor... bom vou colocar aqui: http://www.dropzonejs.com/#installation Como implementar o que falei: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24859005/dropzone-js-how-to-change-file-name-before-uploading-to-folder  Caso precise de um exemplo funcionando tenho os arquivos aqui já.

Comment: Rafael se você nao se importar me passa tanto o codigo que você conseguiu do onRemove do plugin Filer e se não for muito me passa o codigo que você ofereceu ai do DropzoneJS por gentileza. Muito obrigado

Comment: Joao, vou ver como posso fazer o upload desses arquivos e já mando. 
Do que você utiliza até agora, pode colocar assim: `onRemove: function(html,arquivo){console.log(arquivo.name); //Implemente um ajax para remover do servidor.},` DropZone: http://www.filedropper.com/dropzone

Comment: Caso queira também, não precisa baixar o .rar, só abrir um chat me chamar que passo o código de cada arquivo lá.

Comment: Rafael olha deu certinho em partes a parte do onRemove, o problema é que como o meu upload.php ele muda o nome do arquivo e também a pasta quando eu dou o console.log(arquivo.nome) ele me retorna o nome original. Você acha que tem algo que se possa fazer? Obrigado

Comment: Joao, tais utilizando qual? o dropzone ou o outro?

Comment: O antigo, pois ja esta tudo pronto com ele.

Comment: Tou vendo este DropZoneJS é muito legal. Me diz uma coisa Rafael quando eu ja tenho as imagens como eu faço para quando eu carregar a pagina eu ja veja as imagens cadastradas. Adorei o seu código, bem esclarecedor.

Comment: Tenta adaptar como no dropzone, eles criaram um array, e conforme iam upando imagens... eles inserem informações no array.  `fileList[i] = {"serverFileName" : serverFileName, "fileName" : file.name,"fileId" : i };`,  e para remover fizeram assim: `var rmvFile = "";
for(f=0;f<fileList.length;f++){
if(fileList[f].fileName == file.name){rmvFile = fileList[f].serverFileName;}
}if (rmvFile){$.ajax({url:"delete_temp_files.php",type:"POST",data: { "fileList" :rmvFile }}).done(function(data) {console.log("retorno:" + data);});}` foi a adaptação do dropzone, que pode ser feita para o seu caso acredito.

Comment: Ah você quer mostrar tudo o que tem na pasta também então?

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no bate-papo](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/22064/discussion-between-rafael-withoeft-and-joao-nivaldo).

Comment: @RafaelWithoeft bao noite preciso falar com você, me procure no skype joao.nivaldo ou de uma olhada neste post meu por gentileza. http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/55279/dropzonejs-n%C3%A3o-inclui-imagem-na-fila

Comment: Joao assim que possível dou uma olhada....